# Is there a way to ensure a value returned from a c# method is assigned to a variable?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, return-value

I'm writing code which calls a third party web API. The web response is important because it contains details of whether a record was inserted. The API returns JSON representing the object which has been created. The returned ID is required for other inserts, e.g. the id of an address is a foreign key required before you can insert an employee. It could be difficult to keep track of inserted addresses if the returned value is not kept for later use.

Is it possible to annotate or otherwise write a method so that the return value must be assigned? This would mean that the method can't be called without assigning some other variable, and thus you can't accidentally loose the response.

e.g.

```
[MustAssignReturnResult]
public string InsertRecord(string json)
{
    return "{json representing result}";
}
```

I want the compiler to fail if this is not assigned.

```
//this is ok
string result = InsertRecord(json);

//valid under normal circumstances
InsertRecord(json); //but should give a compiler error because result is not assigned.
```

Comment: Why? If the returned information is important for later use, whoever is writing the code will figure that out and store it. I'm not sure enforcing this by the compiler (can't think of a way to do it at this moment) is useful or a good idea.

Comment: Don't do this. Period. *"The returned ID is required for other inserts"* - the usual programmer will figure it out. You don't have to enforce anything.

Comment: @InBetween I think it's useful in this case to help prevent users filling the third party database with junk. E.g. inserting Addresses without Employees. Unfortunately the 3rd party API makes it difficult to search for the address once its been created, i.e. you have to know the ID of the inserted record. I can't stop users only inserting the address but can go someway to make the code warn or error if they look to be doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't force the return value to be assigned.

However, you could move the return value to an `out` parameter, that way the caller does have to declare a variable:

```
public void InsertRecord(string json, out string result)
{
    result = "{json representing result}";
}
```

Now the caller has to say:

```
InsertRecord(json, out var result);
```

However, there's no way you can stop the caller using the discard variable `_` to ignore the result:

```
InsertRecord(json, out var _);
```

Comment: This helps but could be combined with the Resharper suggestion. The point of doing this is the method has external side effects (inserting records to a database) and I want to try to encourage correct usage without assuming people read the documentation start to end.

Comment: @sbmobile - Sure, but relying on Resharper won't help if someone isn't using Resharper.